# Index Error when passing a list to a class

Tags: python, list, class

I have the following code:

```
class TestClass:

    def __init__(self, myint, mylist=None):

        if mylist == None:
            mylist = []
        self.myint = myint
        self.mylist = mylist[:]

theList = [[1,3,4,5,6],[1,2,3],[1],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]]

myOb = []
for i in range(len(theList)):
    myOb[i] = TestClass(sum(theList[i]),theList[i])
    print(myOb[i].myint)
    print(myOb[i].mylist)
```

However **__init__** fails on IndexError: list assignment index out of range.  This I do not understand.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Add `python` tag, to better qualify your question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add:

```
myOb[0] = 1
```

right after you define it to understand - `myOb[i] =` attempts in the first iteration to assign to the first cell (`i=0`) something, but that cell does not exist yet (there are 0 cells). What you want is:

```
myOb.append(TestClass(sum(theList[i]),theList[i]))
```

If you're building `myOb` and don't need the prints, you can use:

```
myOb = map(lambda x: TestClass(sum(x),x), theList)
```

or a list comprehension. Better yet, do the sum yourself in the `__init__`:

```
def __init__(self, mylist):
    ...
    self.myint = sum(mylist)
```

and the map will become:

```
myOb = map(TestClass, theList)
```

Answer (score 0):

So  my oversight is that the list was declared as:

```
myOb = []
```

and then I went right ahead and tried to add elements to the list.  I should have appended them.  I have changed the code to this:

```
myOb = []
for i in range(len(theList)):
    myOb.append(TestClass(theList[i]))
    print(myOb[i].myint)
    print(myOb[i].mylist)
```

and now I get the correct output:

```
19
[1, 3, 4, 5, 6]
6
[1, 2, 3]
1
[1]
45
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

So there.  Rookie error.

P.